# How to convert CSV with Double Quotes into OpenCSV using SED or AWK?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, opencsv

I want to convert the CSV with double quotes into OpenCSV (no double quotes and comma is escaped with backslash) using unix utilities SED or AWK.  I do find examples with perl or java online, but i am looking for one which is simply done using basic SED or AWK.

Comment: Example input/output for those of us who don't know OpenCSV standards?

Comment: Which part of the task is causing you difficulty?

Comment: OpenCSV: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/, https://code.google.com/p/opencsv/ (insert warnings about Sourceforge and Google Code).

Comment: Are we talking about the same opencsv that can be found at [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/) ?  Or is this some CSV standard - in which case could you please provide a link to the standards because when I google opencsv I just get the open source project.   The OpenCSV parser handles double quotes and commas without issue.

Comment: You don't, at least not easily. Use a CSV parser.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about OpenCSV standards, but going by your description you can use this to do a find and replace using SED.

`sed -i -e 's/FINDME/REPLACEWITH/g' folder/file.csv`

Multiple find/replace can be separated by a semi-colon `;`. `-i` edits a file in place and `-e` runs a script.

So for your particular example, backslashes and commas make it a little difficult, but this should work:

`sed -i -e 's/"/'\''/g;s/,/\\,/g' file.csv`

Answer (score 0):

From your description, this might be what you are after:

```
awk -F'" *, *"|^ *"|" *$' '{a="";for(i=2;i<=NF-1;i++){gsub(/,/,"\\,",$i); if(a){a=a","$i}else{a=$i}};print a}
```

A bash example:

```
awk -F'" *, *"|^ *"|" *$' '{a="";for(i=2;i<=NF-1;i++){gsub(/,/,"\\,",$i); if(a){a=a","$i}else{a=$i}};print a}'<<<$'"a","b",","\n"d", "e" ,",,,"'
a,b,\,
d,e,\,\,\,
```